# Threejs :: determine if an object is screened by others

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been developing an 3d model viewer with three.js but I have encountered this problem and I cannot seem to find any solution to it.

I want to have 2d overlay tracking a sphere while it's rotating.
I managed to code the overlay tracking the sphere referring to http://zachberry.com/blog/tracking-3d-objects-in-2d-with-three-js.

But I want to hide the tracking overlay while the sphere is screened by the cude.

So I tried to caculate intesects between camera and the sphere to determine is visible from camera.

But rayCaster.intersectObjects always return 0.

Here is my code.
How can i determain the sphere is visible or not?

```
$(function() {
   // Some defaults/hardcoded values:
   var DEFAULT_VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
var DEFAULT_CAMERA_X = 0;
var DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y = 0;
var DEFAULT_CAMERA_Z = 200;
var PERSPECTIVE_NEAR = 0.1;
var PERSPECTIVE_FAR = 10000;


var WIDTH = $('#viewport').width();
var HEIGHT = $('#viewport').height();

// state
var rotate = true;

// three.js objects:
var renderer;
var scene;
var camera;
var projector;
var container;
var cube;
var sphere;
var pointLight;
var rayCaster;

// elements
var $trackingOverlay = $('#tracking-overlay');

// create three.js elements
projector = new THREE.Projector();
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(DEFAULT_VIEW_ANGLE, WIDTH / HEIGHT, PERSPECTIVE_NEAR, PERSPECTIVE_FAR);
camera.position.set(DEFAULT_CAMERA_X, DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y, DEFAULT_CAMERA_Z);
pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.set(10, 50, 150);
container = new THREE.Object3D();
cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({wireframe: false, color: 0x00CC00})
);
cube.position.set(0, 0, 0);
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({wireframe:false, color: 0xCCCC00})
);

sphere.position.set(0, 64, 0);
container.add(cube);
container.add(sphere);
scene.add(container);
scene.add(pointLight);
scene.add(camera);


// setup viewport
viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
viewport.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// start the animation loop
requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update()
{
    if(rotate)
    {
        // hardcoded rotation for this demo:
        container.rotation.z += 0.01;
        container.rotation.x += 0.001;
        container.rotation.y += 0.025;

    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    positionTrackingOverlay();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function positionTrackingOverlay()
{
    var visibleWidth, visibleHeight, p, v, percX, percY, left, top;


    // this will give us position relative to the world
    //p = sphere.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone();
    p =new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(sphere.matrixWorld);
    // projectVector will translate position to 2d
    v = p.project(camera);

    // translate our vector so that percX=0 represents
    // the left edge, percX=1 is the right edge,
    // percY=0 is the top edge, and percY=1 is the bottom edge.
    percX = (v.x + 1) / 2;
    percY = (-v.y + 1) / 2;

    // scale these values to our viewport size
    left = percX * WIDTH;
    top = percY * HEIGHT;

    // position the overlay so that it's center is on top of
    // the sphere we're tracking
    $trackingOverlay
        .css('left', (left - $trackingOverlay.width() / 2) + 'px')
        .css('top', (top - $trackingOverlay.height() / 2) + 'px');

    if(isSphereVisible()){
        $trackingOverlay.show();
    }else{
        $trackingOverlay.hide();
    }


}
function isSphereVisible(){

    rayCaster.setFromCamera(sphere,camera);
    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(cube.children);
    console.log(intersects.length);

    return intersects.length>0?false:true;
}
```

});